# How to cancel Task without CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested?

Tags: task, appdomain, cancellation

I am developing a WPF application with C# 4.0 where some user-specific code will
be compiled at runtime and then executed inside an AppDomain. The process might take 10 ms or 5 minutes. The AppDomain will be created by *Task.Factory.StartNew()*. Works fine.

Now I want to be able to cancel/interrupt the execution. I can press a
Stop button while the codes is executing but how can I cancel the Task? I know:
there is the *CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested* property but I cannot
loop through something. This is why I cannot check the value while executing
the (atomic) code. And unloading the AppDomain does not stop the Task.

FYI: I took the *Task* class because it easy to use. If *Thread* would be useful: No problem.

Can someone help me? A short code snippet would be nice :).

Thank you.

Comment: You are using System.CodeDom fro compilation right? You could cancel before you start the compilation and before you start loading the new AppDomain and creating the proxy objects. I don't think the CodeDomProvider API allows for cancellation during the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Aborting a thread or a task is a code smell of a **badly designed solution**.

If that is your decision, you should consider that every line of code could be the last one to be executed and consider releasing any unmanaged resource, lock, etc that could leave the system in an inconsistent state. In theory we should always be this careful, but in practice this doesn't hold.

If you try with a *Thread* and the inviting *.Abort()* method, you should consider that *ThreadAbortException* is a special exception in terms of *try-catch* and *finally* blocks. Additionally, you can't even be sure that the thread is going to be aborted.

In regards of using a Task, AFAIK (I'm not an expert in TPL) I'm afraid you cannot do what you want. You should somehow re-design your logic to consider the cancellation token and cleanly stop your computation.